# problema en el render con la nueva actualizacion de react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, funciones

[image: quiero renderizar una funcion en la cual le paso props como parametro y el componente para agregar a favoritos..]

EL ERROR ES EL SIGUIENTE :
index.tsx:24 Matched leaf route at location "/listado" does not have an element. This means it will render an  with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo acudir al [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) y leer el apartado [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), te informo que preguntas que no provean de [un ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de código tienden a ser cerradas, recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta y añadir detalles adjunto al código.

Comment: Es porque las rutas cambiaron en React Router v6. Ahora en vez de `render` debes pasar una prop `element` que contenga el componente que quieres renderizar. [Documentación en inglés](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#advantages-of-route-element)